# Instalação de uma aplicação WinForms C# no cliente

Tags: c#, winforms, instalador

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em WinForms C# em 03 camadas com Banco de Dados Access.MDB:

Agora as questões para que o Aplicativo possa ser instalado no cliente e funcionar corretamente.

1. Os arquivos que mando para o cliente são os seguintes:

   ```
   1.1 - Executável winforms: Ex: MinhAplicação.exe
   1.2 - DLL MODELS: Modelsapp.dll
   1.3 - DLL DAL:    Dalapp.dll
   1.4 - DLL BLL:    BLLlsapp.dll 
   1.5 - BD Access:  database.mdb
   ```
2. Mesmo o cliente tendo o Office instalado (no caso 2010) o C# me obriga a instalar o OLEDB 12.0 no cliente.

   Pergunta: Há alguma maneira do Aplicativo C# reconhecer o Office do Cliente sem eu ter que instalar o OLEDB 12.0
3. Meus relatórios feitos com ReportViwer não rodam no cliente, a não ser que eu instale o Visual Studio no cliente.

   Já tentei mandar o `reportviwer.exe`, o *run-time* do Visual Studio. Mas o C# pede o CRL TYPES DO SQL previamente instalado. Isso é complicado para o cliente.

   Pergunta: Quais os arquivos e procedimentos necessários para que o meu aplicativo instale e rode no cliente?

Comment: Algum problema para usar o instalador que vem com o Visual Studio?

Comment: quando você gerar o executavel, irá tudo pro projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre o report viewer. Procure no site da Microsoft por "Pacote do Microsoft Report Viewer yyyy Redistributable". Ele só vai instalar os binários necessários no cliente para ele gerar o relatório.
Link para versão 2010: [Pacote do Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

Answer (score -1):

Sobre o Access existe o Access Runtime a versão tem que ser a mesma do office que você criou o banco de dados ex: se você criou o MDB no access 2007 baixa o runtime 2007.. Nesse link tem todas as versões:
https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/search/result.aspx?q=Access+Runtime&form=MSHOME

Agora sobre o cliente ja possuir o Office na instalação do mesmo teria de marcar uma opção que seria algo assim: Suporte a Aplicações do .NET se não marcarem essa opção da erro já tive muito problema com isso, Só o Office com access em si aplicação não reconhece. porém o Runtime resolve esse problema.

Uma Recomendação: Tente começar a Usar o MySql ele é simples de se instalar e de usar. Ate mesmo mais simples do que o Access em determinados casos.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89095)

Comment: Obrigado Diego. o Link foi para fornecer ajuda ou facilitar a busca que no caso seria o Access Runtime. Grado da Dica.